# I want to add this 'DotsDiv' element in each of the 'domino' element

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom, javascript-objects

I'm trying to figure how to append two elements with dot class to `domino` class.

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++){

  var domino = document.createElement('div');
  domino.className = "domino";
  document.getElementById('dominoes').appendChild(domino);

}

for (j=0; j<2; j++){

  var DotsDiv = document.createElement('div');
  DotsDiv.className = "dots";
  document.querySelector('.domino').appendChild(DotsDiv);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use nested loops. The external creates `.domino` items, and the internal adds `.dots` items to the current `.domino`.

```js
var dominoes = document.getElementById('dominoes');
var i, j, domino, DotsDiv;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  domino = document.createElement('div');
  domino.className = "domino";

  for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    DotsDiv = document.createElement('div');
    DotsDiv.className = "dots";
    domino.appendChild(DotsDiv);
  }
  
  dominoes.appendChild(domino);
}
```

```css
.domino {
  background: gold;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.dots {
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  background: silver;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="dominoes"></div>
```